# Cast varchar into int, converting any value under 0 to 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cast

I am inserting values form a staging table in SQL Azure into a production table. Values in the staging table are varchar, while the target value in the production table is tinyint (it is an age field for humans, so I reckon that up to 255 will suffice ;) )

Problem is that due to a bug in the source system, we tend to get some values as -1 or -2 when they should be 0. This causes issues, since TINYINT only supports values form 0 to 255 (and also because this is factually wrong). I was wondering if there is some sort of case statement that I could use to convert values to 0 if they fall under 0, or perhaps if they fall outside the 0-255 range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `TINYINT` only allows `0-255` you could also use

```
ISNULL(TRY_CAST(YourCol AS TINYINT),0)
```

The `TRY_CAST` above returns `NULL` if supplied an invalid input for the datatype (including -ve numbers) and I would be minded to leave it that way.

But if you must change these to `0` you can wrap it in an `ISNULL`

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @BadData VARCHAR(100) = '-5'
DECLARE @TinyInt TINYINT

SET @TinyInt = CASE 
        WHEN cast(@BadData AS INT) < 0
            THEN 0
        ELSE @BadData
        END

SELECT @TinyInt
```

Comment: This seems to work! SELECT CASE WHEN cast([fieldname] AS INT) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE [fieldname] END

Comment: Naturally, the result of the CAST still has to be <= 255 or it won't fit into a TinyInt (you'll get an arithmetic overflow)